# Xamarin Forms - Urho - Create scene on page

Tags: c#, xamarin, urhosharp, urho3d

this is the first time i'm using urhosharp and i'm having some issues. I tried following some examples samples but my app is crashing .

I installed the nuget package UrhoSharp.Forms

I just want to create a scene with the camera in the middle that i can rotate 360 degrees.

This is my page :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Urho;
using Urho.Forms;

using Urho.Resources;
using Urho.Gui;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace testApp.Pages.Urho
{
    public partial class urhoPage : ContentPage
    {

        Scene scene;
        Camera camera;

        protected Node CameraNode { get; set; }


        public urhoPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            scene = new Scene();

            scene.CreateComponent<Octree>();
            scene.CreateComponent<DebugRenderer>();

            var planeNode = scene.CreateChild("Plane");
            planeNode.Scale = new Vector3(100, 1, 100);
            var planeObject = planeNode.CreateComponent<StaticModel>();

            // Create a Zone component for ambient lighting & fog control
            var zoneNode = scene.CreateChild("Zone");
            var zone = zoneNode.CreateComponent<Zone>();

            // Set same volume as the Octree, set a close bluish fog and some ambient light
            zone.SetBoundingBox(new BoundingBox(-1000.0f, 1000.0f));
            zone.AmbientColor = new Urho.Color(0.15f, 0.15f, 0.15f);
            zone.FogColor = new Urho.Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.7f);
            zone.FogStart = 100;
            zone.FogEnd = 300;

            // Create the camera. Limit far clip distance to match the fog
            CameraNode = scene.CreateChild("Camera");
            camera = CameraNode.CreateComponent<Camera>();
            camera.FarClip = 300;

            // Set an initial position for the camera scene node above the plane
            CameraNode.Position = new Vector3(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);

           // var renderer = Renderer;
            //renderer.SetViewport(0, new Viewport(Context, scene, camera, null));


        }
    }
}
```

I had to remove those 2 lines as i was getting error . Renderer and context were not set . i got that from the features samples that did not use pages

// var renderer = Renderer;
//renderer.SetViewport(0, new Viewport(Context, scene, camera, null));

Answer (score -1):

1. **floats** The Vector3() for your plane node scale, FogStart, FogEnd and FarClip should be floats.
2. If we don't know the **Context** for your viewport, Urho crashes for sure.
3. Improve stability of your app by replacing 'var' with the typename: Node, Component, Renderer.

   ```
   using Xamarin.Forms;
   namespace testApp.Pages.Urho
   {
   public partial class urhoPage : ContentPage
   {
   Scene scene;
   Camera camera;

   protected Node CameraNode { get; set; }


   public urhoPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       scene = new Scene();

       scene.CreateComponent<Octree>();
       scene.CreateComponent<DebugRenderer>();

       var planeNode = scene.CreateChild("Plane");
       planeNode.Scale = new Vector3(100f, 1f, 100f);
       var planeObject = planeNode.CreateComponent<StaticModel>();

       // Create a Zone component for ambient lighting & fog control
       var zoneNode = scene.CreateChild("Zone");
       var zone = zoneNode.CreateComponent<Zone>();

       // Set same volume as the Octree, set a close bluish fog and some ambient light
       zone.SetBoundingBox(new BoundingBox(-1000.0f, 1000.0f));
       zone.AmbientColor = new Urho.Color(0.15f, 0.15f, 0.15f);
       zone.FogColor = new Urho.Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.7f);
       zone.FogStart = 100f;
       zone.FogEnd = 300f;

       // Create the camera. Limit far clip distance to match the fog
       CameraNode = new Node();
       Camera camera = CameraNode.CreateComponent<Camera>();
       camera.FarClip = 300.0f;

       // Set an initial position for the camera scene node above the plane
       CameraNode.Position = new Vector3(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);

       var renderer = Application.Current.Renderer;
       renderer.SetViewport(0, new Viewport(Application.CurrentContext, scene, CameraNode.GetComponent<Camera>(), null));
   }

   }}
   ```